# Bash script ,which puts all the files in order of size

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I need help with a bash script. The problem is that I want to sort all the files in order of size, but I only need files, not folders,and to show me their size as well.
I have this code but folders also appear:

```
read -p "Enter the size of the top: " MARIMETOP
du  -a | sort -n -r | head -n $MARIMETOP | /usr/bin/awk 'BEGIN{ pref[1]="K";  pref[2]="M"; pref[3]="G";} { total = total + $1; x = $1; y = 1; while( x  > 1024 ) { x = (x + 1023)/1024; y++; }  printf("%g%s\t%s\n",int(x*10)/10,pref[y],$2); } END { y = 1; while(  total > 1024 ) { total = (total + 1023)/1024; y++; } ; }'
```

Comment: We can't help you fix your script if you don't show what you have so far. We're not going to write it for you.

Comment: Can you use zsh instead?

Comment: Yes,i can use zsh .

Comment: I think you could use `find` command here: `find . -type f -exec du -a {} +`

Comment: `ls -l | grep  "^-r" | sed -e's/  */ /g' | sort -n -t' ' -k5 -r`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will print all regular files in the current directory and subdirectories sorted by size:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n100000 ls -Sl
```

or if you want only size and filenames:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n100000 stat -f "%z %N" | sort -n -k1 -r
```

With the `-n100000` flag this will handle at most `100000` files found by `find`.

Answer (score 1):

`find` from GNU findutils can print the file size

```bash
find . -type f -printf '%s\t%p\n' | sort -k1,1nr
```

- `%s` = file size
- `%p` = file path (use `%f` for just the file's basename)

Comment: If you're looking to print _disk usage_ (not just file size), use the `%b` printf directive (number of 512-byte blocks)

Answer (score 1):

While the OP tagged the question by *bash*, he said in a comment that a zsh solution would also be OK. In *zsh* you could write it as

```
du *(.OL)
```

Explanation:

```
.   : Only consider plain files
O   : Sort descending
L   : Sorting criterium is the length of the file
```